# Download rss as xml (by default it returns html)

Tags: c#, xml, string, download, rss

Here is the link
https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id=126895537502383

The problem is that when I download it by WebClient DownloadString() / DownloadData() method it gives me html code

**note:** it seems that source depends on which browser I will open the link, on google chrome I see a nice xml code, but in Firefox I see this stuff polished with HTML

So... how can I download native xml code of this link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the `User-Agent` header

```
var wc = new Webclient();
wc.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Stackoverflow/0.0";
var xml = wc.DownloadString("https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id=126895537502383");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DownloadFile method of WebClient class.

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadFile("https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id=126895537502383", @"C:\feed.xml");
```